# Error in path to binary in multistage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm lost at trying to get my executable to run in a multistage Dockerfile.

I keep getting

```
"Exec user process caused: no such file or directory unknown"
```

errors relative to the path to the binary I've built in the first stage, so I know I'm referencing it wrong.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Does the `WORKDIR` argument apply to the second stage of the build, as well?

```
#####################################
# PHASE 1: build an executable binary
#####################################
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o server .

#####################################
# PHASE 2: build a small disk image
#####################################
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/server /app/server
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "/app/server" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are building the executable for the same machine without explicitly turning off `CGO_ENABLED` then it does build binaries that are dynamically linked and when cross-compiling it tries to build a static binary. You can confirm the same by using `ldd <executable_path>` after building the executable if it's dynamically linked or not.

So, you are building on an `alpine` base and then copying it to the `scratch` base which doesn't have those libraries to be dynamically linked.

Hence, build static binaries first and then copy the same, it should run. See if `CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o server .` works or not. There could be more depending on your code; so basically you have to create a statically linked executable and it should run fine on a distro-less base.

Comment: Thank you much! That did it. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Yep, great. Could you please accept the answer? It'd help others find the solution if they face a similar problem.